# How to pass in ID with Html.BeginForm()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) I'm using the HTML helper

```
Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post);
```

But I need to post to: /controller/action/23434

How do I pass in the ID?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Matt's should work fine.  If you are still passing in `FormMethod.Post`, though, you need to do it like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("action","controller", new { Id = 12345 }, FormMethod.Post);
```

Reversing the third and fourth parameters will result in the `Id` being treated as an attribute instead of a route value.

Comment: I am losing the existing route values when I am using this method. Say my url was `/controller/action?type=golden`, the form target (using your way) now becomes `/controller/action/12345` while I want it to be `/controller/action/12345?type=golden`. Do you know any way I could preserve the existing route values and append my own too?

Comment: @Aki Try adding `type` as a hidden field within the form and it should get sent along.

Comment: I could, but you see that's not my problem. Its not necessary that I have only `type` in my query string, I could have N number of params, which might be different in different actions. It would be a real pain to go into all those actions and add the query params as hidden fields.

Answer (score 10):

`Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new {Id = 12345})`

Comment: check the parameter name routeValues - make sure you are using that one not htmlAttributes.

Answer (score 7):

```
Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { id = ViewBag.FileID },
FormMethod.Post, new { id = "feedbackform" })
```

As for the querystring, `?type=golden`, I don't know how to do that. Of course, a querysting is a get, and undermines the whole purpose of `FormMethod.Post`.  I mean, you could use `FormMethod.Get`, if you want querystring data, and this might be what you are looking for.

Additionally, you can avoid `html.beginform` and do the querystring, get + post, manually with a form tag.

Thirdly, if you are using the form, you can make a hidden field:

```
[input type=hidden name="type" value="golden"]
```

Then, when the submit button is pressed the value is passed properly as a form variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- ACTION: Category/Update/Id | Method:Post-->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Category",new {Id = @Model.Id },FormMethod.Post)){}
```