# How can I name a form with Html.BeginForm()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I give a name to a form in ASP.NET MVC using `Html.BeginForm()`? **I want only the name, not the action or controller name** because I want to post it through Javascript. I think it should be something like `Html.BeginForm(id = "frm")`.

I tried the following:

```
Html.BeginForm(null,null,new{id="frm",name="frm})

Html.BeginForm(new{@id="frm",@name="frm})
```

But the above code produces output like this:

```
<form action="/Main/Index/Id?name=Id" method="post">
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" })
```

You'll need to catch the form submit with your JavaScript

Comment: Thanks   But your solution produce this code <form action="/Main/Index/frm?name=frm" method="post">

Comment: Helped me a lot, and your blog is also a treat. Thanks BritishDeveloper :)

Comment: Make sure you put id = "frm" after the GET or POST or the id value will be passed to the controller (if any).

Answer (score 9):

Using MVC2, this is what worked for me:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post, new {@id = "myForm", @name = "myForm"})) {%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@HTML.BeginForm("Target-ViewName where you want to post the page","Controller Name",new {@name="Name of the Form", id="ID of the Form"}) 
{ //form here
}
```

Comment: Instead of "Target-ViewName where you want to post the page" I think you mean "Target action method to which you want to post the data".

Answer (score -5):

Taken from this answer: [How to pass in ID with Html.BeginForm()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878330/how-to-pass-in-id-with-html-beginform)

Can you not just do:

```
Html.BeginForm(new {@id="Id", @name="Id"});
```

It can pay to search SO for answers as I've found many things I want to ask have already been encountered.

Comment: you're adding route values though. not html attributes

Comment: I see your answer where you're passing in nulls, I did think you could just use the defaults for the named parameters and pass in a list of additional attributes to append to the output HTML

Comment: i tried your solution before but it generate code like this  "<form action="/Main/Index/Id?name=Id" method="post">"

Comment: Sorry about that, I did think that was the way it worked - obviously not.  In that case, this might be a good example of when to provide your own HTML extension method, or just revert back to good old HTML.