# Razor Form 2 submit buttons with confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, razor-2

I have simple form in Razor and I want add confirm dialog before save or remove before post. How can I do this?

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Car", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        <p class="button">
            <button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" name="remove">Remove</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am beginer I try use jquery confirm function but withnout succes

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to prevent normal form submission and ask for confirmation, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421293/confirmation-of-form-submission-using-jquery)

Just give your `Html.BeginForm` tag an id, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683366/how-can-i-name-a-form-with-html-beginform)