# asp.net mvc razor getting id with post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how can i get the querystring id in there? is there any way

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InformVendor", "Procurement",new {id="querystring Mode = "Inform" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
<tr>
    <td>
          @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.VendorId,new MultiSelectList(Model.VendorDropdownlist, "CustomerId", "ContactName"))   
     </td>
    <td>
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsEmail)
   </td>        
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
         <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" value="Nominate Vendor" />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass in ID with Html.BeginForm()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878330/how-to-pass-in-id-with-html-beginform)

Comment: You mean to set form id from your querystring?

Comment: I can do it with viewdata or something similar but can i access it directly

Comment: Yes, I guess. Try `id = Request.QueryString["id"]`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have your id field be hidden.  This way the user doesn't see the ID field but your post back controller does.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.YourID)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the Id to your view model and render it as a hidden field.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

You will be able to retrieve it like this instead of using the querystring.

```
public ActionResult InformVendor(AViewModel model)
{
   var Id = model.Id;
}
```